# Making a dynamic QMenu in QT

Tags: qt, qmenu

I have a `QMenu`, where I want to add `QActions`. The problem is, everytime the table is clicked, the existing menu adds onto itself. How do I stop it from doing that?
So when I click on the table, it should be new menus everytime.

```
void MainWindow::onTableClicked(const QModelIndex &index){
       QAction *action;
//    action->setAutoRepeat(false);


    if (index.isValid()) {

        QString cellText = index.data().toString();
        QString indexRow = QString::number(index.row());
        QString indexCol = QString::number(index.column());
        ui->textBrowser->setText(indexRow + "\n"+ indexCol);
        QSet<int> possiblevalues =  findPossibleValues(index.row(),index.column());

        for(int n : possiblevalues){
            listofPossibleValues.push_back(QString::number(n));
        }

        for(auto s :listofPossibleValues){
            action = myMenu.addAction("Set Value "+s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`QMenu::clear()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#clear), is this what you need?

Comment: @thuga i dont really want the whole menu to be cleared. just the action. but clear still does not work.

Comment: I am confused. I thought you wanted new set of actions every time you click on the table. Could you explain a bit more what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @thuga Yes i want new set of actions but preferably including other permanent actions. the action that is getting repeated onto itself is the last line of code action = mymenu.addaction... I want that to be new everytime the table is clicked and clear() does not remove all the actions in mine

Comment: So maybe it's your `listofPossibleValues` list that contains the duplicate values?

Comment: @thuga yes good point. I actually added popfront after action = mymeny.addaction.. 
the menu still adds onto itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it looked like myMenu.clear wasnt working was because i did not remove listofPossibleValues after I added the menuaction. I was able to fix it by adding

```
 //At the beginning 
 myMenu.clear(); 


//At the end
listofPossibleValues.clear();
```